How to automatically add -E flag to sudo when starting Vim from Bash
I'm looking for a way to always start Vim as a sudo using -E "preserve environment" flag. Running sudo with this flag allows Vim to load .vimrc file and all themes/shortcuts.
I tried to write a .bashrc function that would add '-E' after 'sudo' if 'sudo' and 'vim' were detected, but I wasn't able to get it working; here is my attempt:
vim() {
    if [[ $1 == "sudo" && $2 == "vim" ]]; then
        command sudo -E vim "$@"
    else
        command vim "$@"
    fi
}


(Obligatory comment pointing out the dubious premises of the question.)

@romainl Can you please explain what you mean by "dubious premises"?

You should probably not use $ sudo vim -E often enough to need an alias for it.

Question is not if I need, question is if I want :D
I love customizing my linux and bash.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

To run sudo vim using your .vimrc you can do this:

Set the $VIMINIT variable in your .bashrc script:

if [ -f "$HOME/.vimrc" ]
then
        export VIMINIT="source $HOME/.vimrc"
fi


In /etc/sudoers add this line so that the $VIMINIT environment variable is passed into the sudo environment:

Defaults    env_keep += "VIMINIT"

This allows you to run sudo vim using your own custom .vimrc if it exists.

Sorry if this is obvious, but can you please specify where I should add Defaults    env_keep += "VIMINIT" line in /etc/sudoers?

Sure! You can simply add it at the bottom of the file.

In my case I already had similar lines so I added it at the bottom of the paragraph:
Defaults    env_reset Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS" .... (other lines) Defaults    env_keep += "VIMINIT"

In your vim function $1 expands as the first argument of vim, not as the token before vim on the command line. You cannot parse the command line backward like this. The simplest solution would probably be to define a sudo_vim function and call this instead of sudo vim ...:
sudo_vim() { sudo -E vim "$@"; }


Thanks for the answer! But note that the -E flag is passed after 'sudo', not after 'vim', so the function would look more like sudo_vim() { sudo -E vim "$@"; } .

This solution is easy and reliable but requires use of custom command, therefore not perfect.

Oops, thanks, I fixed the typo.

I am not sure I understand why this solution that "requires use of custom command" (custom function would be more accurate) is less perfect than your original attempt with another custom function (vim). Can you please explain?

Sorry, if I wasn't clear enough, I meant I can't use this function by typing just "sudo vim", I have to type "sudo_vim". But I don't want to complain, your solution is a good way to do it.

Ah, I see. It is less perfect than using plain sudo and vim. If your goal is only to use your .vimrc have a look at kityo's solution, it looks promising.

By the way, is there any reason why you don't use sudoedit?

It doesn't always work:
[f0x@Arch Documents]$ sudoedit temp.txt
sudoedit: temp.txt: editing files in a writable directory is not permitted

Ah, yes, if you want to edit files in directories where you have write permission you must disable sudoedit_checkdir (by adding Default !sudoedit_checkdir to /etc/sudoers). But this is not recommended because it allows users to bypass all restrictions of sudoedit (see this).
